# Scope of a LiteralControl problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, scope

I have a piece of code that creates dynamic controls using 2 while loops.
As you can see, I am forced to declare both LiteralControls INSIDE each while loop because if I don't, the `puBugList.Controls.Add(lineBreak)` will not acknowledge.

Q: Why can I not see the scope of the controls from inside a while loop?

```
    //this control is not acknowledged
    //LiteralControl lineBreak = new LiteralControl("<br/>"); 
    while (nwReader.Read())
    {
        int id = (int)nwReader["bid"];
        string user = (string)nwReader["buname"];
        string prob = (string)nwReader["bproblem"];
        string content = id + ". " + user + ": " + prob + "<br/>";
        Label lb = new Label();
        lb.Text = content;
        phBugList.Controls.Add(lb);

        //forced to declare 1 here
        LiteralControl lineBreak = new LiteralControl("<br/>");

        String sqlSelRep = "SELECT * FROM [reply] WHERE bid=@bid";
        SqlCommand cmdSelRep = new SqlCommand(sqlSelRep, conn);
        cmdSelRep.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid", id);
        SqlDataReader repReader = cmdSelRep.ExecuteReader();
        while (repReader.Read())
        {
            //forced to declare another 
            LiteralControl lineBreak2 = new LiteralControl("<br/>");one here
            string msg = (string)repReader["rmsg"];
            Label lbRep = new Label();
            lbRep.Text = "Admin: \"" + msg + "\"";
            phBugList.Controls.Add(lbRep);
            phBugList.Controls.Add(lineBreak2);
        }
        repReader.Close();


        if (Convert.ToInt32(Session["user"]) == 1)
        {
            phBugList.Controls.Add(lineBreak);

            TextBox tbRep = new TextBox();
            tbRep.ID = "tb" + id.ToString();
            phBugList.Controls.Add(tbRep);

            LinkButton butRep = new LinkButton();
            butRep.ID = "rep" + id.ToString();
            butRep.Text = " Reply";
            butRep.Click += InsertReply;
            phBugList.Controls.Add(butRep);

            LinkButton butDel = new LinkButton();
            butDel.ID = "del" + id.ToString();
            butDel.Text = " Delete";
            butDel.Click += DeleteBug;
            phBugList.Controls.Add(butDel);

            phBugList.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
        }
        phBugList.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "will not acknowledge"? That `lineBreak` is not in scope?

Comment: It means that the code compiles, but the end-result doesn't display any linebreak effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'r problem is that if you instantiate `LiteralControl` outside the while loop you are effectively using the same object throughout your code, and you cannot add the same control twice to a `Controls` collection of another control.

Try the following:

```
 LiteralControl lineBreak = null;
 (...)

 while (repReader.Read())
 {
      literalControl = new LiteralContro(...);
 }
```

Anyway, unless you need `lineBreak` in scope outside the while loop there is nothing wrong declaring the variable inside the loop so your code is perfectly fine.